# How to use system desktop colors in CSS3?

Tags: css, user-interface, colors

CSS2 had a [nice way](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css2-system) to implement system desktop colors. However in the link there is a note that this is **deprecated** and

> If you want to emulate the look of a user interface related element or
>   control, please use the ‘appearance’ property instead of attempting to
>   mimic a user interface element through a combination of system colors.

But from [the example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) the `appearance` property is useful to render form elements like checkbox or button.

How am I supposed to use `appearance` to emulate say **table** using system colors? To omit the color specification works for borders, but not for backgrounds.

Sometimes I'd like to create simple webs that displays dark if the user has dark system desktop settings. It can be done specifying no color at all in CSS. But If I want say slightly darker (or lighter on dark desktops) background on headings, how to do it in CSS3? (In CSS2 I could use i.e. ButtonFace color.)

Comment: I guess, simply, you don't. Means we have to work harder...oh well.

Comment: The good news is that you can't tag your stylesheet with a version number. So your browser won't know you're cheating. In other words, just use those system colors already. And if you're worried about the W3C validator, well, you're also using vendor prefixes aren't you.